# Debugging simultaneously in Intellij/Webstorm and Chrome dev tools

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

With the latest versions : Intellij 13 or Webstorm 8.

It's cool to be able to debug the code in the IDE. But Chrome dev tools brings search in the DOM / inspect element which is lost when debugging in the IDE.

Actually the IDE debug session stops as soon as the chrome dev tools are open.

IS it possible to avoid that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No:( Unfortunately the javascript debugger in WebStorm/Idea can't co-exist with Chrome dev tools. It's Chrome problem that can't be solved on JetBrains side. Please vote for http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129539

Comment: sure - you can debug in FireFox and dev tools at the same time

Comment: Sadly the issue url is locked for comments and since 2013 that no answers. Do you know about any update?

Comment: I encounter this problem for a long time. It is really annoying. Recently I found Brackets has the similar feature named Live Preview. I believe they have similar ways of implementation. But Brackets Experimental Live Preview can work normally when Dev Tools is on. Though this is claimed by intelliJ as the bug of Chrome, Brackets teams seemed to think of new means to solve that. Why shouldn't webstorm learn from the way of Brackets?

Comment: Do we still has same same issue with Chrome ? Maybe we have some other way to debug same time in chrome and webstorm ?

Comment: yes, the issue is still actual. Please see  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129539

Comment: It's finally [fixed](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#multi-client).

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer using chrome dev tools you can always open up 2 x chrome browser sessions and use one for the live edit connection to the jetbrains ide, and the other session to inspect elements etc.

Answer (score 1):

[As of Chrome 63 this is now possible](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#multi-client).